# gitlab: git clone ssh still prompts for password, ssh -T is working

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-clone

I am aware of all the questions regarding SSH login to a gitlab instance still prompting for a password, but none of the answers describes what I am experiencing.

**Expected** behavior: git clone works without prompting for a password, since it uses the stored SSH key to authorize against a running gitlab instance.

**Actual** behavior: I get a password prompt for user "git" instead of cloning the repo.

I am trying to clone a git repo on windows using Git bash from my own gitlab instance, but I still get prompted for a password despite the fact, that `ssh -T git@host:port/path/to/repo.git` is working properly.

```
$ ssh -T git@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 12345
Welcome to GitLab, @User!
```

I did the following steps:

1. create a SSH key pair, upload public key to gitlab
2. open git bash (windows) and test the SSH connection using `ssh -T`
3. try to clone the repo (using the same git bash) with the following command: `git clone --progress -v "ssh://git@host:port/path/to/repo.git"`

`eval 'ssh-agent'` returns a PID, I even tried `ssh-add` to add the SSH identiy again. But since the SSH connection is working properly, the problem seems to be the `git clone` command which simply ignores my SSH identity.
If the gitlab server was the problem, `ssh -T` should not work, right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: You posted the reproduction steps, but you forgot to describe what (problematic) thing actually happens: do you get any error messages? Also: is this on Linux or on Windows? If the latter, what git distribution have you installed and with which settings?

Comment: Did you actually read my question or even the title? Nevertheless, I added a clarification paragraph for better understanding.

Comment: Check your secure log on the gitlab server, if you have access to it, or ask those who do. The file might be called something else on a different platform, but on Centos it's `/var/log/secure`. There should be something in there for every ssh attempt, whether it's failure/successful, and no matter if it's git clone or ssh. If it doesn't lead you in the right direction, could you update your post with the relevant lines in there (redact as necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. Had a long forgotten but still active TortoiseGit installation from medieval times. That was messing with the `$GIT_SSH` environment variable, leading to the use of TortoisePlink and thus ignoring my local .ssh config for git bash.

After removing TortoiseGit everything is working as expected.